# Python 2.7: Put extracted data from URL in a CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, beautifulsoup

This is my first time using Python 2.7, I do like it. However, I am trying to figure out how I can put extracted data from the URL into a CSV file. I found [this tutorial](https://programminghistorian.org/lessons/intro-to-beautiful-soup#stripping-tags-and-writing-content-to-a-csv-file), but when I run my script:

```
# import libraries
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# specify the url
quote_page = 'http://www.bkfrem.dk/default.asp?id=19'

# query the website and return the html to the variable ‘page’
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# create CSV file
csvfile = csv.writer(open('firsteam.csv', 'w'))
csvfile.writerow(["Name", "Position"])

# take out the <div> of name and get its value
items = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'visTruppenContainer'})

for i in range(len(items)):

    playerInfo = items[i].getText(separator=u' ')
    imageURL = items[1].find('img')['src']
    csvfile.writerow([playerInfo, imageURL])
    print (playerInfo)
    print (imageURL)
```

I get this error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/script2.py", line 26, in <module>
>     csvfile.writerow([playerInfo, imageURL])
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe5' in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
> ```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to convert the data before writing to the CSV file?

Comment: `encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: What should I encode? The output?

Comment: Can you use python 3 instead?

Comment: Yes in `csvfile.writerow([playerInfo, imageURL])` (I can't try it because when I convert this to Python 3 it works) so I can't tell you where exactly but it is certainly in one of those two

Comment: Yes, now I don't get the error anymore, but the CSV file is empty :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to encode the `playerInfo` like:

#### Code:

```
csvfile.writerow([playerInfo.encode('utf-8'), imageURL])
```

#### Results:

```
1. Marco Brylov Position: Målmand Højde: 191 Vægt: 92 Født: 21-11-1995
http://www.bkfrem.dk/images/spillere/02_mikkel_andersson.jpg
2. Mikkel Andersson Position: Midtbane Højde: 170 Vægt: 67 Født: 17-03-1990
http://www.bkfrem.dk/images/spillere/02_mikkel_andersson.jpg
3. Casper Andersen Position: Midtstopper Højde: 190 Vægt: 90 Født: 04-08-1982
http://www.bkfrem.dk/images/spillere/02_mikkel_andersson.jpg
...
```

Comment: Thank you alot. When I open the csv file, it's, for some reason, empty